# Make a function clickable only while a timer is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am attempting to learn JavaScript/jQuery and I am trying to create a simple countdown app. The user can set the amount of time and then click on the displayed value to start the countdown. While the countdown is happening, if the user clicks the displayed value again, I want to pause the countdown (please note that in my code I am simply using an alert message because I haven't gotten to the part of coding the pause yet). So far, everything appears to work. However, when the countdown has ended, the user should be able to choose a new countdown time and again click the display to start the countdown. However, when I click on the display, it runs the alert message multiple times before starting the countdown. Basically, the user should be able to click the display while the timer is running to pause the countdown. If the countdown is not running, then clicking the display should cause simply start a new countdown.

Here is my HTML:

> ```
>   <div class="value-display">
>   <button class="btn" id="increase" onclick="increase()">+</button>
>   <h1 id="display" onclick="startTimer()">5</h1>
>   <button class="btn" id="decrease" onclick="decrease()">-</button>
>   </div>
> ```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var total = 5;
var counter;

function increase() {
  total += 1;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = total;
}

function decrease() {
  if (total > 0) {
    total -= 1;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = total;
  }
}

function startTimer() {
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function timer() {
  if (total === 0) {
    document.getElementById("increase").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("decrease").disabled = false;
    clearInterval(counter);
    return total;
  } else if (total > 0) {
    total -= 1;
    document.getElementById("increase").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("decrease").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = total;

    $("#display").click(function() {
      alert("ok");
    })
  }
}
```

Here is the codepen:

http://codepen.io/jv1149/pen/PzqKqQ/

Comment: It really doesn't help that you have both inline event listeners AND event listeners in your JS script. They're clashing with each other.

Comment: Also, you can either: both add an event listener and remove the event listener, OR you can put a condition IN the event listener that checks on the timer. But just putting the add event listener in a conditional statement doesn't turn it on and off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clearInterval() when the total reaches zero as well.

I would not define the display.click function in the timer function either

You may want to save the display in a var as well in order to not have to search it every time

```
var total = 5;
var counter;
var increase = document.getElementById("increase");
var decrease = document.getElementById("decrease");
var display = document.getElementById("display");

function increase() {
  total += 1;
  display.innerHTML = total;
}

function decrease() {
  if (total > 0) {
    total -= 1;
    display.innerHTML = total;
  }
}

function startTimer() {
  increase.disabled = true;
  decrease.disabled = true;
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function pauseTimer() {
 increase.disabled = false;
 decrease.disabled = false;
 clearInterval(counter);
}

$("#display").click(function() {
  if(total===0) startTimer();
  else pauseTimer();
})

function timer() {
  if (total === 0) {
    pauseTimer();
    return total;
  } else if (total > 0) {
    total -= 1;
    display.innerHTML = total;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This still doesn't work exactly how I want. Once I have started the timer, it never seems to stop. For example, if I start the timer and it gets down to zero, the timer should be done and I can add more time and start over if I want. However, as soon as I add using the buttons, the countdown continues, even if I don't click the display to start it again.

Comment: Did you remove the onClick in the markup for the display. You might also have an easier time styling a div for this rather than using h1

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new variable `state` which keeps the current state of the timer. Ex: 0 = stopped, 1 = paused, 2 = running.

You can then change your `startTimer()` method to be `changeState()` which checks the current state of the timer and then performs the appropriate function. Ex: `(if state === 2) { pauseTimer(); }`

From there I think you can finish modifying your code to implement `startTimer()`, `pauseTimer()`, and `stopTimer()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You got most of the parts working! However your code is not working because...

1) Your click function was wrapped within your `display` function, so every time the `timer()` function  was being called, it attached another event listener.

2) Also you have both inline event listeners and listeners in your js file-they're competing with each other. Keep your event listeners in the same scope.

Here's the working code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrqarP

**HTML:**

```
<div class="value-display">
  <button class="btn" id="increase">+</button>
  <h1 id="display" onclick="startTimer()">5</h1>
  <button class="btn" id="decrease">-</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var total = 5;
var counter;

function increase() {
  total += 1;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = total;
}

function decrease() {
  if (total > 0) {
    total -= 1;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = total;
  }
}

function startTimer() {
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(counter);
}

function timer() {
  if (total === 0) {
    document.getElementById("increase").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("decrease").disabled = false;
    clearInterval(counter);
    return total;
  } else if (total > 0) {
    total -= 1;
    document.getElementById("increase").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("decrease").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = total;


  }
}

/* see how I played the event listeners both 1) outside of the timer() function and 2) away from your HTML */

$("#display").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("ok");
})

$("#increase").on("click", function() {
  increase();
})

$("#decrease").on("click", function() {
  decrease();
})
```

For future reference, please read: https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried this codepen but I'm still having some issues. First, everytime I click on the display, I get the "OK" alert, when I only want the OK alert if the timer is running. Also, it seems like the timer is always running. For example, after the countdown reaches 0, it should end and I should be able to add more time, but as soon as I add more time, the timer starts again.